# Fused Location Manager API Accuracy

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I want to make an Android app that needs locations accurate to about 1m or less. 
Is the "Fused Location Manager API" good enough, or can GPS never be this accurate, regardless if fused with other Sensors?
If so, does anybody know a way to get more accurate locations on a smartphone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Getting more accuracy in Android phones was not recommended due to battery/data consumption. If it not an issue means you can use below code

```
Integer gpsFreqInMillis = 1000;
Integer gpsFreqInDistance = 1;  // in meters

locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(gpsFreqInMillis, gpsFreqInDistance, criteria, this, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

For GPS 3m is max see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43617/what-is-the-maximum-theoretical-accuracy-of-gps It wont get any better than that. And that is outside and away from any buildings.

All other sensors are less accurate. Maybe you can get some better accuracy if you take multiple measurements over time and average them (works only with a still device).

You can get very good results with wifi rtt (which is not strictly a sensor)  https://www.gpsworld.com/how-to-achieve-1-meter-accuracy-in-android/ which is used by [Fused Location Provider](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/)

Answer (score 0):

There has been a previous discussion about whether the Fused Location Provider is a good choice (the answer to that question was yes). You can find that post here: [Is Fused Location Provider good choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072991/is-fused-location-provider-good-choice)

Perhaps this is what you are looking for: [Android's most accurate Location API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578575/androids-most-accurate-location-api)

Hopefully this helps!